# Shopware 6 API: invalid media file path after creating

Tags: php, api, shopware, shopware6

I'm using the [media API](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/c5267f85b987c-create-a-new-media-resources) to create the media files for my Shopware 6.4 platform.

From the administration everything looks good and the files are there, but when I try to get the media file (download), it fails due to the incorrect file path.

**The problem:** The files were imported into different directories (the directories are created based on the hash of the uploaded_at + file_name value).

**Example:** The file `media/04/9a/e9/1683563547/file_name.pdf` is located in the actual path `media/2a/4e/e9/1683564352/file_name.pdf`.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

By default the path naming strategy uses the `id`.
That means the first three parts of the path are actually [derived from the `media` `id`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/dad17d74f238a44846b00d46c376c96e8b99488b/src/Core/Content/Media/Pathname/PathnameStrategy/AbstractPathNameStrategy.php#L49).

```php
$mediaId = '02eb1f1416504d7d86552f3c60e32aee';
$hash = md5($mediaId);
// b0b1095a8c2d6c965723996880bc0331
// would yield a relative path /media/b0/b1/09/xxxx/xxxx.xxx
```

There are different strategies following the same principle but [will use the file name](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/dad17d74f238a44846b00d46c376c96e8b99488b/src/Core/Content/Media/Pathname/PathnameStrategy/FilenamePathnameStrategy.php#L25) for hashing instead of the `id`.

The strategy can be changed at `config/packages/shopware.yml`

```yaml
shopware:
    cdn:
        strategy: "id"
```

or via `.env`

```
SHOPWARE_CDN_STRATEGY_DEFAULT="id"
```

Did you by some chance happen to change the strategy from `id` to `filename` or vice versa? If so, try changing it back.

If you didn't, did you migrate data from one Shopware installation to another? If you simply copied the `media` folder but the ids of the `media` table have changed, it would also explain the mismatch of paths. Then you would have to re-upload the files properly.

Comment: I don't have a `config/packages/shopware.yml` actually the package folder is empty .. should I create one instead? and usually it is in xml type

Comment: You can overwrite settings by creating `yml` files inside the directory. If you haven't created one it will just take the default values from the files in `src/Core/Framework/Resources/config/packages`. If you didn't change your strategy in your `.env`, your filesystem and database are simply out of sync.